# How can I extend object by mapping name with specific id from another object?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am thinking to use _.extend and _.map but I am not sure how exactly. I am new to Lodash.

```
const students = [
    {'studentId': 1, 'name': 'Beth'},
    {'studentId': 2, 'name': 'Tina'}
];

const marks = [
    {'studentId': 1, 'score': '123'}, 
    {'studentId': 1, 'score': '200'}, 
    {'studentId': 2, 'score': '99'}
]; 

I want output as:
[
    {'studentId': 1, 'name': 'Beth', 'testScore': '123'}, 
    {'studentId': 1, 'name': 'Beth', 'testScore': '200'}, 
    {'studentId': 2, 'name': 'Tina', 'testScore': '99'}
];
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

create object map of studentId: name.
map over marks and add name.  rename score to testScore.

```js
const stus= [
    {'studentId': 1, 'name': 'Beth'},
    {'studentId': 2, 'name': 'Tina'}
];

const marks = [
    {'studentId': 1, 'score': '123'}, 
    {'studentId': 1, 'score': '200'}, 
    {'studentId': 2, 'score': '99'}
];



const stumap = stus.reduce((a,x)=>(a[x.studentId]=x.name,a),{});

console.log(JSON.stringify(
marks.map(({studentId, score:testScore})=>({studentId, testScore, name: stumap[studentId]}))
))
```